# How to record microphone audio when using external monitor

Tags: macos, audio, microphone, recording, macos-ventura

macOS Ventura v13.4.1
MacBook Pro 14 M1
External Samsung monitor

I've been struggling for hours on how to record the built-in microphone audio when making a screen recording using the default macOS functionality (cmd - shift - 5) The video recorded, but not the audio.

On a whim, I opened the laptop lid, which switched the display from external monitor to the MacBook display. Recording screen capture with external audio now works. Shocked me. :-(

Can anyone provide info on how to record with the built-in microphone when using the external monitor? (am somewhat visually challenged. need a huge display.)

I've looked at System Settings -> Sound and Security & Privacy -> Microphone, but don't see anything amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to clarify, it sounds like you are trying to record using the built-in Macbook microphone while the lid on your Macbook is completely closed. If so, then I'm afraid it is working as intended. For security reasons, Apple disconnects that microphone when the lid is closed.

Here is a [related article](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/hardware-microphone-disconnect-secbbd20b00b/web).

Comment: Yes, external monitor, so lid closed.   thanks for clarifying and thanks for the link….informative.

Answer (score 0):

From the Options menu in  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  you should be able to choose from any audio source currently connected.

[image]

I can't test if built-in mic shows as an option when the lid is closed in clam-shell mode, I don't have any similar setup here - though it would likely be unusably muffled with the lid closed, even if it does show as an option.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have VLC for Mac, it can be used, too. https://www.tuneskit.com/record-audio/record-audio-from-vlc-media-player.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - but doing screen recording in VLC is a convoluted nightmare compared to the Mac's built-in single key-press recorder. I doubt if the Mac can't see the mic that anything else would be able to. The OS would shut it down as a source if it can't currently be used - like if it's buried inside a closed laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my own solution.

In System Settings -> Displays, I opened the lid enough to wake up the built-in display.  I then set my external monitor as the main display and turned the brightness down on the built-in display.

With the lid *almost* closed, it does not obscure the external monitor and the microphone is active.

Always open to alternative solutions.  Thanks for your input.